# How to tell which email/phone number an iMessage was sent from

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, facetime

I've got a few addresses that I can be reached at, one phone number and two email addresses. I know which address new conversations are started from, but how can I tell which of my phone number/emails a current conversation is being sent to?

(I want to change my number in iMessage but I don't want to have to message everyone to update them just in case they're sending messages to my phone number instead of my email address on iMessage.)

Is there a way to check my recipient email address/phone number of each convo? Thanks!!

Comment: It's so baffling that the Messages app on IOS just lumps chats by the individual in Contacts rather than the channel of communication, cell phone 1, cell phone 2, email X, email Y. I can't even determine an unambiguous way to see what conveyance a particular message was sent over.

Comment: Looks like a lot of others have this question too [How to find the phone number text message sent from?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7447332)